# VB.NET Match string between parentheses (brackets)

Tags: regex, vb.net, match, brackets, parentheses

Looking for a pattern for matching text between brackets.
For example: `"(this is) a (test)"` should output

```
"this is"
"test"
```

Using `Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(str, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)`

I have searched stackOverflow, Google and tried examples on RegExr and nothing seems to work for me.

These work on RegExr but in not VB.NET

`"\(([^)(]++|(?R))+\)"` - error nested quantifier

`"(?<=\<p\>)(.*?)(?=<\/p\>)"` - quantifier following nothing

Others will return:
`"this is) a (test"` - matching far outer brackets

PS I could also do with the same for

`[],"",{}`

it would be good to have them all in one place for anyone looking under vb.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\((.*?)\)`

Your regex is very complicated! This one will grab all text in between two `()` and match the inner text. [Play with it here](http://regexr.com?31u61).

Comment: Thank you! I have found I had two errors (moved from javascript to VB.NET). One is that the regex does not support the same features. The other is using Match instead of Matches.

Comment: @user759885 No problem. If my answer helped you, please mark it "accepted" by hitting the checkmark underneath the vote count.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to explain how this Regex works? I'm trying to set up a function which removes text in Japanese brackets （）, but I don't know enough about Regexes to change yours.